# How to give a console application (local system) authentifcation for a signalR hub on a webserver

Tags: .net, authentication, signalr, owin

So we have an IIS that runs on windows authentification and our asp.net has a basic signalR hub:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class DemoHub : Hub
    {
        public void SendHello(string text)
        {
            Clients.All.hello(new Random().Next() + " - " + text);
        }
    }
```

We have a console application client that is also simple:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "http://localhost/";

        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);
        hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("DemoHub");
        await hubConnection.Start();

        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Type something!");
            var text = Console.ReadLine();
            await hubProxy.Invoke("SendHello", new [] {text});
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the client uses Windows Credentials `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` but in a production environment this won't work since the console will be a windows service running on `local system` and the web server will be located on a machine in the intranet.

What are my options here? (SSL)-Certificate is not an option unfortunately. Can I use a Token? Is there any option where we don't have to rewrite the IIS or the whole server authentification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a similar console app to monitor my IIS host and send updates every 5 seconds about various performance counters to a monitoring page to updated charts/graphs and other elements.

I run the console app as a scheduled task using a Windows account, where I can enter the credentials it should run as. This is a dedicated account for running services, scheduled tasks, etc... As you generally would not use your own credentials.

As far as running as a Windows Service, this should also be applicable. Use an account that has appropriate permissions on the IIS Host and have the service setup to run with those credentials.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped it could somehow work with local.system, guess we need to have windows credentials than.